# Difference between react-redux v6 and v7 that causes error?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Thanks for answering my question in advance.

```
{
  ...
  "react": 17.0.1,
  "react-redux": 7.2.2,
  "redux": 4.0.5,
  ...
}
```

This is my `package.json`. Everything worked perfectly when I was using `react-redux 6.0.0`.

But after I upgrade it to v7, nothing is rendered in website. I didn't touch any other codes. I'm using `connect` method of `react-redux` to use redux store. Of course, `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.

Is there any difference between v6 and v7 that causes this error?

Comment: Shouldn't happen... Did you check the release note? Maybe you will find answers [there](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases)...

Comment: Check out the dependency-tree in your logs ... it could require a specfic-version of `redux` module

Comment: You can install all dependencies again (remove node_modules, and lock files and run npm/yarn install). Are there any build errors or errors in the browser console when you run the project?

Comment: There shouldn't be any meaningful difference from a code perspective.v6 and v7 are 99.8% API compatible except for a couple of minor option changes.